# How to drag and drop Browsed stl element with three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d, drag-and-drop

I'm building a Stl viewer/editor. I'm a beginner in JS and i'm supposed to be able to load and move  (and eventually scale, rotate) STL file. All i've done here is this : A 
3D field where you can upload STL but only if they are at the same place than the file ( you cannot browse an stl place anywhere else) and move camera.
I'm trying to add a drag and drop function but find nothing that is suitable. Found [this](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_interactive_draggablecubes.html) but it seems to be obsolete function no longer used by three.js.
I find [this](https://threejs.org/examples/#misc_controls_transform) witch look very good but : the camera don't move and it's not an STL file and i haven't been able to "adapt" it to my code.
Can someone please help me ? As i said i'm a beginner so be as detailed as possible otherwise i wont understand.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset=utf-8>
  <title>LOAD THE POULE</title>
  <style>
   body { margin: 0;
       background-color: white;
     }
   canvas { width: 100%; height: 100%; color: blue; }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <script src="js/three.js"></script>
  <script src="js/OrbitControls.js"></script>
  <script src="js/STLLoader.js"></script>
  <script src="js/Detector.js"></script>
 
 
   <form action="">
    <input type="file" id="poule">
  </form>
  <script>
   var camera, scene, renderer;

   init();
   animate();

   function init() {

    document.getElementById("poule").addEventListener("change", onFileSelected);

    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera
    (75, window.innerWidth /window.innerHeight, 1, 10000);
    camera.position.set(10,20,25);
    camera.lookAt(scene.position);


    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize ( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    <!--light-->

    var light = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff);
    light.position.set(-100,200,100);
    scene.add(light);
    var light = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff);
    light.position.set(100,-200,-100);
    scene.add(light);

    <!--Grid-->

    var size = 14, step= 2;

    var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
    var material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({color: 'white'});

    for(var i= -size; i<= size; i +=step){
     geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(- size, 0,i));
     geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3( size, 0,i));
     geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(i, 0, - size));
     geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3( i, 0,  size));
    }
    
    var line = new THREE.LineSegments ( geometry, material);
    scene.add(line);

    <!--cam controls-->
    controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

    <!--base-->

    var plane = new THREE.Mesh(
     new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry( 2*size +5, 2*size +5,0 ),
     new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0x424858, specular: 0x101010 } )
    );
    plane.rotation.x = -Math.PI/2;
    plane.position.y = -0.1;
    scene.add( plane );
    plane.receiveShadow = true;

    <!--Cube-->

    var sphere = new THREE.SphereGeometry();
    var object = new THREE.Mesh
    ( sphere, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial
    ( 0xff0000 ) );
    var box = new THREE.BoxHelper( );
    scene.add( line );

    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.BoxGeometry
    ( 2*size, 2*size,  2*size ),
    
    new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial() );
    var helper = new THREE.BoxHelper( mesh );
    helper.material.color.set( 0x00ffff );
    scene.add( helper );
    helper.position.set(0, size, 0);


    animate();
   }

    function animate(){


    requestAnimationFrame(animate);


    renderer.render(scene, camera);
    controls.update();

   }

   function onFileSelected(event)
   {
    <!--STL Loader-->

    var loader = new THREE.STLLoader();
    var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( {
     color: 0xAAAAAA, specular: 0x111111,shininess: 200 
    } );
    poule = event.target.files[0];
    console.debug(poule)
    loader.load( poule.name, function ( geometry ) {
     var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
     mesh.position.set( 0, 0, 0 );
     mesh.rotation.set( - Math.PI / 2, 0, 0 );
     mesh.scale.set( 2, 2, 2 );
     mesh.castShadow = true;
     mesh.receiveShadow = true;
     scene.add( mesh );   
    });
   }     
   
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Why would a beginner do this ? I have to..

Comment: I think the primary hurdle will be understanding what javascript can do and what you can do with JavaScript. Three.js in my opinion requires a deep level understanding of JavaScript to build an effective application beyond showing a model and spinning it around. Finding a canned example to your specifications is going to be unlikely. Have you checked any of the Related links on this page? --->

Comment: I know but i 'work' in a firm for 3 month for my studies and they want me to do that despite the fact i told them this was above what i think i'm able to do. So i've been trying for many days and decided to post here to get help because i don't find many answer on the web. I'll go check you'r link thanks !

Comment: Deep breath! It'll be ok. Get as far as you can using your own code. Post individual questions on particular aspects of the code that isn't working rather than asking for an overall approach - this is simply not what stackoverflow is for. So if on step one, loading STL files, isn't working, post a question with your code. At each step, examine and solve the problem at hand and take one step at a time.